# SOAP Action mismatch error while testing a WCF service with SoapUI

Tags: wcf, soapui

Am testing a WCF service with a sample input in SOAPUI. when i hit the run,I get an SOAP Exception like below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
     <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
<s:Body>
 <s:Fault>
     <s:Code>
        <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
        <s:Subcode>
           <s:Value>a:ActionMismatch</s:Value>
        </s:Subcode>
     </s:Code>
     <s:Reason>
        <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://XXX.XX.XXXX/IXXXXXX/AddOrderInfromation'.</s:Text>
     </s:Reason>
     <s:Detail>
        <a:ProblemHeaderQName>a:Action</a:ProblemHeaderQName>
     </s:Detail>
  </s:Fault>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

In blogs, they are asking to add Soap Action . How to Add Soap Action in my request below:

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wkus="http://XXX.XX.XXXX/IXXXXXX">
  <soap:Header />
  <soap:Body>
  <ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ns1:inputsting>
<ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
  <ns1:OrderNo>4500146</ns1:OrderNo>
  <ns1:OrderDate>08/22/2014</ns1:OrderDate>
  <ns1:TotalItems>1</ns1:TotalItems>         
</ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
 </ns1:inputsting>
 </ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
```

Please Suggest. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 37):

This is probably a `WS-A` addressing issue.

In the `WS-A` tab of your Request, check `Enable WS-A addressing`.
You may also have to check `Add default was:To`.

Comment: May be need to try other `WS-A addressing` settings as well. In my case i had to change the `WS-A version` from `200408` to `200508`

Answer (score 7):

Your web service is returning a SOAPFault which is saying that web service expects a SOAP Action http header. In order to add a SOAP action in your SOAP request from SOAPUI you must add a http header named `SOAPAction`, to do so do the next step:

- In the bottom of your SOAP test request there are some tabs (`Header(0)`, `Attachments(0)`...), open the `Header(0)` tab.Then using `+` add button, add a header with `SOAPAction` name and your value:

[image]

hope this helps,

Comment: Yes thats right. Can you also reply how to add this using a Java client. I generated the stubs using Apache Cxf from the wsdl.

Comment: @james2611nov take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767209/how-do-you-add-a-soap-header-defined-in-a-wsdl-to-a-web-service-client-in-cxf) which explains a possible way to add the SOAPHeader in http-header using CXF. If this doesn't fit your requirements try to ask your own question with more details about your exact problem. Hope this helps `:)`

Comment: I posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653718/adding-soap-action-header-using-java  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too, and solved it by enabling WS-A addressing in SopaUI.
[screenshot from SoapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mfT4.png)

Answer (score 4):

This error also occurs due to improper  syntax in xml request

For Eg : It will throw same error if
closing tag is missing

```
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in below code

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wkus="http://XXX.XX.XXXX/IXXXXXX">
    <soap:Header />
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
            <ns1:inputsting>
                <ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
                    <ns1:OrderNo>4500146</ns1:OrderNo>
                    <ns1:OrderDate>08/22/2014</ns1:OrderDate>
                    <ns1:TotalItems>1</ns1:TotalItems>         
                </ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
            </ns1:inputsting>
        </ns1:AddOrderInfromation>
```

or if having unexpected syntax like this

```
    <ns1:OrderNo>4500146**<ns1:OrderNo>**
```

instead of

```
    <ns1:OrderNo>4500146**</ns1:OrderNo>**
```

or this

```
    <ns1:**OrderNo**4500146</ns1:OrderNo>
```

instead of

```
    <ns1:**OrderNo>**4500146</ns1:OrderNo>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered similar problem. And I solved the issue like below;

https://blabla.com/xyz.svc?wsdl -->go to the wsdl url on browser and you will see some actions inside methods;

[image]

I use python for development and i added soapAction like below;

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
           'SOAPAction': 'http://tempuri.org/IArasCargoIntegrationService/GetQueryXML'
           }
```

and it worked.